# SQL Replace Inside Update using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hey guys I been trying to tackle this problem on my own for a while but  I need some help here is my code:

```
UPDATE prop_Notes 
SET Notes += 
            (
              CASE 
                   WHEN Notes LIKE '%<p>" + ProductName + @"</p>%'
                   THEN replace(Notes,'<p>" + ProductName + @"</p>', '<p>" + ProductName + @"</p>')
                   ELSE '<p>" + ProductName + @"</p>'
              END
            )
FROM prop_Notes
```

I want to be able to add/Append a new string into my sql column Notes if it does not already contain that string inside it. If it exists simply replace the existing item, so the string will not change. I am getting error saying Ambiguous Column Notes when I try to run this. Any help would be appreciated Thank you!

Comment: Alias the table?

`UPDATE pn
SET Notes += 
            (
              CASE 
                   WHEN pn.Notes LIKE '%<p>" + ProductName + @"</p>%'
                   THEN replace(pn.Notes,'<p>" + ProductName + @"</p>', '<p>" + ProductName + @"</p>')
                   ELSE '<p>" + ProductName + @"</p>'
              END
            )
FROM prop_Notes pn`

Comment: You don't need `FROM prop_Notes`.  It is redundant and causing the columns to be ambiguous.

Comment: Do any of your other tables in the query have a column called Notes?

Comment: I edited my question to include the complete call, I need the `FROM` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is the `from` statement.  You can fix the ambiguous column just by removing it.

I would suggest that you consider a simpler alternative, something like this, if I understand your problem correctly:

```
UPDATE prop_Notes 
    SET Notes = coalesce(Notes, '') + '<p>" + ProductName + @"</p>'
    where Notes not LIKE '%<p>" + ProductName + @"</p>%'
```

In that case, you need to learn about aliases in `updates`:

```
UPDATE pn
SET Notes += 
            (
              CASE 
                   WHEN Notes LIKE '%<p>" + ProductName + @"</p>%'
                   THEN replace(Notes,'<p>" + ProductName + @"</p>', '<p>" + ProductName + @"</p>')
                   ELSE '<p>" + ProductName + @"</p>'
              END
            )
FROM prop_Notes pn
```

Comment: I need the `FROM` statement since this Update call is inside a bigger SQL Statement, I will post the complete SQL Statement Maybe it will give bigger picture

Comment: Thanks Sir, Learned something today such as `Alias` ^^